# ManytoMany relationship to insert data into table

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, many-to-many

Authentication .java

```
        @Entity
        public class Authentication {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name="authenticationId")
            long authenticationId;

            @Column(name="username")
            String username;

            @Column(name="password")
            String password;

            @Column(name="confirmPassword")
            String confirmPassword;

            @Column(name="ENABLED")
            int enabled;

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinTable(name = "userrole",joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "authenticationId", nullable = false, updatable = false)},       inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
            Set<Role> roleSetInAuthentication = new HashSet<Role>();
```

Role .java

```
    @Entity
    public class Role {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="roleId")
        long roleId;

        @Column(name="roleName")
        String roleName;    

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roleSetInAuthentication")
        Set<Authentication> authenticationSetInRole = new HashSet<Authentication>();
```

AdminController.java

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
           public String displayForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
            List<Role> roleList = adminService.getRoleCategory();
            request.getSession().setAttribute("roleList", roleList);
            return "admin";     
        }
```

admin.jsp

```
            <form:select path="">
            Assign Role<option value="SELECT">--SELECT--</option>
            <c:forEach var="r" items="${roleList}">
            <option value="${r.roleId}">${r.roleName}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
```

I am using spring mvc form, have created manytomany relation becoz of which a separate table(userrole) is getting generated,having field as authenticationId, roleId.Do i need to insert the data in (roleuser) table manually, but i guess i am making manytomany relationship, so data shud get inserted ino this table automatically, but in jsp how to write code and make the use of relationship so that the data shud get inserted into this table by itself, and i need not to enter manually.i was just trying admin.jsp bt not getting it exactly.

Comment: Can you please tell what you didnt get

Comment: when admin from dropdownlist, select the role(details coming from RoleTable) for any user(details coming from AuthenticationTable) , the data in the third table i.e (userrole table) shud get inserted by itself, we need not to enter data in third table manually, means how it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third table is called linking table. n:m relationship each of Authentication has multiple role and vice versa.

So In object level Authentication has collection of Role and Role has collection of Authentication.

While inserting the table ORM first insert data into Role and Authentication . Id of Role and Id of Authentication  will be insert into Linking Table.

While removing one role from Authentication, It just remove the linking table entry and vice versa.

While retrieving role , it will fetch the Authentication from the reference of linking table and vice verso.

Its totally **automatic no manual.**

Comment: so, when i am inserting data into Authentication and not in Role table then in linking table how it would insert in both column(i.e authenticationId and roleId), becoz i m only inserting data into authentication table not in Role table, what happens in this case. Means when i am working with both the tables simultaneously at that time data get inserted into linking table othrwz not .??

Comment: Not exactly . Thing is you can have cascade option. If you are cascade operation is insert Athentication --> Role then role will be inserted while inserting Athentication and vice versa.